# Two conditions in a do-while loop in C++

Tags: c++, do-while

I have been trying to make a linear feedback shift register, but there is something wrong in the code that I haven't been able to find, I tried to diagnose the problem by having the condition of the do-while loop that handles  the main operation of the program, that is xoring the bits and shifting them, to be either one of two:

```
 operSeq !=inpSeq 
 turnCount < 31.
```

The program asks the user to enter 5 bits as the initial card of the LFSR, then he/she has to enter a second binary sequence representing the the polynomial: if it is `x^5+x^4+x^2+x^1+1;` the sequence that the user should enter is `10111`, these bits are examined if any of them is one, it's location will be stored in a vector named `xorArray`. As a test case for this code, if the user enters `10101` for the initial card and `01111` for the poly location, the program will generate an indefinite number of binary sequences, those sequences do not follow what the xor operation correctly as it seems, and also they don't terminate after 31 turns as the do-while loop specifies! I need help diagnosing this code. Here is it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // int x, y;
    int turnCount = 0;
    bitset <5> inpSeq;
    bitset <5> polyLoc; 
    bitset <5> operSeq;
    bitset <5> bit;
    vector <int> xorArray;
    vector <int> keyReg;

    cout << "Enter a 5-bit sequence: \n";
    cin >> inpSeq;
    cout << "Enter poly: \n";
    cin >> polyLoc;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0;  i < polyLoc.size(); i++)
    {
       if( polyLoc[i] == 1)
       {
          xorArray.push_back(i);
       }
    }

    cout << "----" << "\n";
    operSeq = inpSeq;
    keyReg.push_back(inpSeq[0]);

    int x = xorArray[0];
    bit[4] = operSeq[x];
    do
    {
       for ( unsigned int j = 1; j < xorArray.size() ; j=j+1 )
       {
          bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[j];
       }

       operSeq >>= 1;
       operSeq[4]  = bit[4]; 
       cout << operSeq << "\n";
       keyReg.push_back(operSeq[0]);
       turnCount ++;
    } while ((operSeq != inpSeq) || (turnCount < 31));

    cout << "Generated key is: ";
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < keyReg.size(); k++)
    {
       cout  <<  keyReg[k];
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Bit 1 positions: ";
    for ( unsigned int g = 0; g < xorArray.size(); g++)
    { 
       cout << xorArray[g];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Key length is: " << keyReg.size();
    cout << "\n";
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `I need help diagnosing this code`. Did you write the code? If you did, why not use the debugger that comes with your compiler suite to diagnose the code?  Very few people write flawless programs the first time, so we debug the code using the debugger to see where the code goes against the plan we had.  Have you done that?  If so, what values does the while() statement have when you claim it's supposed to terminate?

Comment: I have wrote it on my own, and it compiles with no errors! I compiled it with g++ on ubuntu, the compiling command is the only thing I know about g++. I have no knowledge of the debugger, any hint?

Comment: The debugger is "gdb".  You won't go far if you don't know how to use it.  Also, this statement `and it compiles with no errors!` -- That means nothing in terms of how the program will run.  A correctly compiling program only means that the program uses correct C++ syntax.  Looks like you weren't prepared for a mandatory step in learning how to write programs, and that is debugging.

Comment: If you're serious about learning to program, Google "gdb", find a tutorial, and do it.  If you want a hack, put another cout just before the `while()` statement that shows you all the variables involved.  Look at what is printed, then decide what's wrong.  "Mental" debugging (staring at your code) usually isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the AND && operator and not the OR || operator on your do {} while loop. You want the loop to continue as long as both the conditions are true, not as long as one of them is true.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is `(operSeq != inpSeq) || (turnCount < 31)`. So if either of the conditions is true, then it will continue to loop. You want to stop the loop when `turnCount >= 31` so your condition should be `(operSeq != inpSeq) && (turnCount < 31)`.

Comment: This solves a problem, thank you. I have an other problem that is that the sequences generated are not as they should be. If the user enters 10101 for the initial card and 01111 for the polyLoc, a 32 bit length key will be generated, if you take a look on the last 2 turns generated: 10100 and 01010, you will find that xoring the first four bits from the right of 10100, the result is 1 not 0!

Comment: See my comment above on learning how to debug.  Put print statements all over the place until you can see EXACTLY what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If your while loop isn't processing anything after turnCount reaches 31, then it's picking up (operSeq != inSeq).

In your while's || statement, if the first condition is true, it won't process the second condition at all.  Try putting turnCount's condition first if (operSeq != inSeq) or && them together if they both need to be true to run.

Would have done this as a comment, but don't have the rep yet :/

Comment: The order doesn't matter since there are no side-effects.

Comment: @clcto What is meant by "side effects"?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed [Side Effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) are when the state of the program changes. For example, `if( i++ == 2 && j-- == 2 )` the order matters, because `j--` has side effects (it decrements the value of `j`), but it is only executed if `i++ == 2`. If the program had `if( j-- == 2 && i++ == 2 )`, the execution would not be the same, as `j--` would always be executed, but `i++` may not be.